# Looking for a plugins for organization portal (Staff, Units, Departments)?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I am looking for a plugin for internal organization portal that will display all the member of 

the organization also the hierarchy between the differents units and departments.

Also I will be able to move one person from one departments to another.

if someone know of such a plugin or could guide me to how to solve it will be great.

Comment: Plugin recommendations aren't typically accepted as valid questions because they are often opinion based. That being said, the paid Types and Views plugin may be appropriate for it's relational capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best thing that exists as a plugin for you to use is "[buddypress](http://buddypress.org)"

this plugin has a lot of features for interacting users with each other but i think it's not exactly what you need! but the good news is buddypress itself has a lot of plugins to install! first install buddypress on your wordpress site and then try its free plugins. better than nothing i think!